BAC0/Bacpypes in Python 3.x - Implementing positiveIntegerValueObject
I'm new-ish to Python, and in working with the BAC0 and Bacpypes Python libraries, I've noticed that not all BACnet object types are fully implemented by default, or if they are, their usage escapes me. One such object type is positiveIntegerValue. I can create a positive_integer_value object, but I cannot read it like I have been reading other object types (characterstringValue, largeAnalogValue).
The following code works with other object types, just not positiveIntegerValue. Both the client and server are connected on the same subnet, I've broadcast a who-is, etc etc...
I create a virtual BACnet device with the following object in a Jupyter Notebook:
positive_integer_value(instance = 10, 
name = "Power", 
description = "Instantaneous Power",
units = "watts", 
presentValue = 18)

I then use bac0.connect and connect it, and the device starts without issue. I then try to read the object using:
self.bacnet = BAC0.connect(ip=192.168.1.1, port=47808)
av = self.bacnet.read("192.168.1.2 positiveIntegerValue 10 presentValue")

After executing the above code in a separate program in PyCharm, the following error occurs in my Jupyter Notebook:
exception: TypeError('invalid constructor datatype')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\*path*\python\python38\lib\site-packages\bacpypes\app.py", line 382 in indication
    helperFn(apdu)
  File "c:\*path*\python\python38\lib\site-packages\bacpypes\service\object.py", line 65, in 
  do_ReadPropertyRequest
    value = datatype(value)
  File "c:\*path*\python\python38\lib\site-packages\bacpypes\primitivedata.py", line 657, in __init__
    raise TypeError("invalid constructor datatype")
TypeError: invalid constructor datatype
   

My PyCharm program also throws an error, but it's complaining about one of my list indices being out of range. Likely because of the error being thrown in the virtual device.
Can anyone offer any advice? I've tried poking around in the files of both libraries, as well as their documentation, with no luck. I need PIVs for a device that my program will be used with down the line. For now, I'm just in testing.

You may have more luck with the new version of bacpypes3 and BAC0
